# How to click and add another Fragment in one Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

How to click and add another Fragment in one Fragment?

There is a button click to add Fragment in one Activity. There is another button in firstFragment. I want to click the button and add secondFragment. How to realize this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fragment1, inflate an XML layout with a button. Set the button's onClickListener and define an onClick method.

```
    // In Fragment1...
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutWithButton, container, false);
            Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
            b.setOnClickListener(this);
            return view;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.layoutWithButton:
                Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2;
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment2); // where container is the FrameLayout where Fragment 1 was first placed
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Depending on how you want to handle your back stack, you can include `transaction.addToBackStack(null);` as needed.